# Unable to click a pagination next button for multiple times - javascript

Tags: javascript

I have written a script which clicks a specific button after a short interval of time. The button is click through javascript, and I put the interval of 2 seconds in between. But the script only executes once and only one time the button is clicked I don't know why :

Below is my script:

```js
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("paginate_button next")[0];
setInterval(function() {
  el.click();
  console.log("Clicked !");
}, 2000);
```

The pagination is given on [this page](https://www.bmwgroup.com/en/careers.html). You can test the code on the console of that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element is probably being removed and recreated when you advance to the next page. So do `getElementsByClassName` inside the `setInterval` callback, so that it retrieves the new element each time.

Answer (score 1):

try to catch the element with jquery

```js
var el = $('.paginate_button.next')



setInterval(function() {
  el.click();
  console.log("Clicked !");
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="paginate_button next" aria-controls="jf-table" data-dt-idx="7" tabindex="0" id="jf-table_next">Next</a>
```